# como puedo seleccionar uno de los 6 arrays al azar?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

_0=(Mami  Bebe  Princesa  Mami)
_1=("Yo quiero " "Yo puedo "  "Yo vengo a " "Voy a ")
_2=(Encenderte  Amarte  Ligar  Jugar)
_3=(Suave  Lento  Rapido  Fuerte)
_4=("Hasta que salga el sol " "Toda la noche "  "Hasta el amanecer "  "Todo el dia ")
_5=("Sin anestecia " "Sin compromiso " "Feis to feis " "Sin Miedo ")

b=$(( $RANDOM % 6 ))

echo _$b[@]
```

como puedo seleccionar uno de los 6 arrays al azar e imprimir su contenido?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer exactamente?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta fedorqui, lo que quería en ese momento era seleccionar uno de los 6 arrays de forma aleatoria, y luego de forma aleatoria seleccionar una palabra, para luego formar una frase, luego de tantos golpes de novato me entere que eso que tenia en la mente era un arreglo de dos dimensiones cuyos datos puedo seleccionar de forma aleatoria. por lo menos aprendiendo java lo logre.. jeje..

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en donde dice

```
"Sin anestecia"
```

debe decir

```
"Sin anestesia".
```

En fin, bromas aparte, no se entiende bien lo que quieres hacer. Si lo que quieres es formar una frase juntando al azar un elemento de cada array declarado, la manera sería generar 6 valores random y pedir la posición de éstos en los arrays de arriba. Y ojo, tus arrays tienen 4 elementos, por lo cual tienes que aplicar módulo 4 y no módulo 6.

```
#!/bin/bash

_0=(Mami  Bebe  Princesa  Mami)
_1=("Yo quiero " "Yo puedo "  "Yo vengo a " "Voy a ");
_2=(Encenderte  Amarte  Ligar  Jugar);
_3=(Suave  Lento  Rapido  Fuerte);
_4=("Hasta que salga el sol " "Toda la noche "  "Hasta el amanecer "  "Todo el dia ");
_5=("Sin anestesia " "Sin compromiso " "Feis to feis " "Sin Miedo ");

a=$(( $RANDOM % 4 ));
b=$(( $RANDOM % 4 ));
c=$(( $RANDOM % 4 ));
d=$(( $RANDOM % 4 ));
e=$(( $RANDOM % 4 ));
f=$(( $RANDOM % 4 ));

echo ${_0[a]} ${_1[b]} ${_2[c]} ${_3[d]} ${_4[e]} ${_5[f]};
```

Lo cual generaría frases como

```
Bebe Voy a Encenderte Lento Toda la Noche Sin compromiso
Bebe Yo puedo Amarte Fuerte Todo el dia Sin Miedo
Mami Yo puedo Encenderte Fuerte Todo el dia Feis to feis
```

Pero como dije antes, no me queda claro lo que quieres hacer. Si quisieras que tu programa imprima los valores de uno de los 6 arrays en orden random, la lógica es distinta.

En otras palabras, si tú quieres que tu programa retorne el segundo array "Yo quiero" "Yo puedo" "Yo vengo a"...  dado un parámetro ingresado por consola o generado al azar, lo que estás tratando de hacer implícitamente es una lista asociativa anidada. Y eso en bash no existe.

Comment: A la final lo hice modificando un poco la respuesta de un usuario de nombre vasan: b=_$(( $RANDOM % 6 ))[@]
echo ${!b}                                                                                                                                                                                                             ___________________________________________                                                                                     c=$(( $RANDOM % 4 ))
b=_$(( $RANDOM % 6 ))[c]
echo ${!b}

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amenadiel, lo que quería en ese momento era seleccionar uno de los 6 arrays de forma aleatoria, y luego de forma aleatoria seleccionar una palabra del array antes seleccionado, para luego formar una frase, luego de tantos golpes de novato me entere que eso que tenia en la mente era un arreglo de dos dimensiones cuyos datos puedo seleccionar de forma aleatoria. por lo menos aprendiendo java lo logre.. jeje.. – Eduardo Espinal hace 40 minutos